# getUserMedia() without SSL for local storage

Tags: html, ssl, getusermedia

In my website I need to record audio from the microphone and then replay it.
I do not need to send those files to the server, they can remain on the client.
Currently I'm successfully using flash for that, but I would like to switch to html5 and getUserMedia().
I'm aware that I normally need SSL for using getUserMedia() (except from localhost use), but I'm wondering if there is some sort of exemption if I don't want the data to be uploaded (and thus there should be no security issues in using it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no exemption. Having one would require running your script in some sort of local sandbox with separate local storage and no networking. Does not exist.

Only Google Chrome enforces this `https` requirement by the way. Other browsers do not.

Getting a [free certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/) is easy.

Comment: Thank you, I expected this answer, but I was looking for a confirmation

Comment: I'm also aware that Chrome is maybe the only browser nowadays that requires https for getUserMedia(), but since it's one of the most common browsers, it would make no sense to ignore it. I will go for a free certificate, thanks again.