# How do I start video streaming using webRTC?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I am writing the following code for starting my camera and watch my video on the Google Chrome browser using the technology webRTC. There are two files I have created index.html and client.js. I have attached the code of both. Node.js server is installed on my PC. The problem is my camera is switching on but I am unable to see the video streaming.

**client.js**

```
function hasUserMedia() { 
   //check if the browser supports the WebRTC 
   return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || 
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia); 
} 

if (hasUserMedia()) { 
   navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
      || navigator.mozGetUserMedia; 

   //enabling video and audio channels 
   navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, function (stream) { 
      var video = document.querySelector('video'); 

      //inserting our stream to the video tag     
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); 
   }, function (err) {}); 
} else { 
   alert("WebRTC is not supported"); 
}`
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang = "en">

   <head> 
      <meta charset = "utf-8" /> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
   </head> 

   <body> 
      <video autoplay></video>
      <script src = "js/client.js"></script>     
   </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getUserMedia() without SSL for local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260985/getusermedia-without-ssl-for-local-storage)

Comment: Chrome requires https. Should work in Firefox though. Also, as the answer mentions, you've copied some really old code.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using old code, now API's got changed better get started with latest API.

See [Demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/) and [Source](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/getusermedia/gum/js/main.js#L50)

Try below snippet in your client.js

```
var constraints =  { audio: true,  video: true};
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
   var video = document.querySelector('video');
   video.srcObject = stream;
}).catch(function(err) {
     console.log('Error in getting stream', err);
});
```